# Parse XML file with windows batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

How can I extract an STRING like "US_NY" between the tags `<LOCATION></LOCATION>` from a XML file? I tried it with FINDSTR, but the line breaks are problematic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DEVICE>
    <AGENT>
        <VERSION>
            2.0.0.2
        </VERSION>
        <CONNECTION>
            <LOCATION>
                US_NY
            </LOCATION>
            <SERVERIP>
                127.0.0.1
            </SERVERIP>
            <TCPPORT>
                5656
            </TCPPORT>
            <POLLINTERVAL>
                5
            </POLLINTERVAL>
        </CONNECTION>
    </AGENT>
</DEVICE>
```

Comment: What is the logic to determine what needs to be extracted?

Comment: I want to get the locations from somde devices. This information is stored in different XML files. Therefore I need to extract the STRING or line between the xml tag `<location>` and `</location>`. This should be done with windows batch script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A batch file to extract the value of a specific XML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217765/a-batch-file-to-extract-the-value-of-a-specific-xml-tag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One more

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "xmlFile=%~1"
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /n /i /c:"<LOCATION>" "%xmlFile%"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%xmlFile%" ^| more +%%n') do set "location=%%l" & goto endLoop
    )
:endLoop
    echo %location%
```

Comment: @lucy, Look at the third line. `xmlFile` is assigned the file name passed as argument to the batch file. So, yes, it is the name of the file.

Comment: using `findstr` has a major problem because it makes the command rely on xml file formatting. If you put multiple tags on the same line it fails to match the pattern!!

Comment: @Greenish, i agree, xml handling from batch scripts should be done with something like xmlstartlet, but a) it is a non native solution (a problem for some environments) b) the problem in the OP question is the line breaks.

Answer (score 15):

You should use XML.EXE within batch to read an XML file. For more details go to http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

**Batch File:**

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('XML.EXE sel -t -v "//LOCATION" CP.xml') do set var=%%i
echo LOCATION is %var%
```

**output:**

```
LOCATION is US_NY
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -small script that will allow you to get an xml node/attribute value by xpath expression without using external binaries.

For your case it can be used like this:

```
call xpath.bat  "location.xml" "//LOCATION"
```

or to assign the value to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a  in  ('xpath.bat  "location.xml" "//LOCATION"') do (
   set "location=%%a"
)
```

---

Pure batch solution

```
 @echo off
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<LOCATION>" some.xml') do ( 
         set begin_line=%%L
        )

        for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "</LOCATION>" some.xml') do ( 
         set /a end_line=%%L+1
        )

        echo showing lines between %end_line% and %begin_line%
        break>"%temp%\empty"
        for /f "delims=" %%l in ('fc "%temp%\empty" "some.xml" /lb  %end_line% /t ^|more +4 ^| findstr /B /E /V "*****" ^| more +%begin_line%') do (
         set "location=%%l"
         goto :break_for
        )
        :break_for
        echo %location%
        del /Q /F "%temp%\empty"
```

Replace `some.xml` with the name of your xml.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a helper batch file (by aacini) then this will work:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findrepl /i "<location>" /e:"</location>" /o:+1:-1 ^< "file.xml" ') do echo "%%a"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

Comment: Clever dual-usage script, both CMD and JScript using built-in CScript.  It even re-use itself to type the help if need be.

Comment: `findrepl.bat`  is no longer available for future generations.

Answer (score 3):

Pure batch -

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "location="&SET "grab="
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (q19722041.xml) DO (
 IF DEFINED grab SET location=%%a&SET "grab="
  IF /i "%%a"=="<LOCATION>" SET grab=Y
)
ECHO found location=%location%
GOTO :EOF
```

where q19722041.xml is your source `.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lastLine=0
< input.xml (for /F "delims=:" %%a in (
              'findstr /N /C:"<LOCATION>" input.xml') do (
   set /A skip=%%a-lastLine+1, lastLine=%%a+2
   for /L %%i in (1,1,!skip!) do set /P line=
   set /P "line=!line!" & echo:
))
```

*Note: the answer is an adaptation of the answer (probably given by [@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)) on this forum post: [Windows batch FindStr to search for a string and matching line](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1716).*

Answer (score 0):

[sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
sed -n "/<LOCATION>/{n;p}" file.xml
```

---

in a batch file:

```
for /f %%a in ('sed -n "/<LOCATION>/{n;p}" file.xml') do set "location=%%a"
echo(%location%
```