# BATCH Script to insert return character to XML file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I need to parse some information from an XML file that does not have any return characters using a batch script.  My strategy is to make a copy of the XML file and insert the proper return characters, then parse out the lines I need.  The goal is to insert a return character between the '><' characters.

The XML file example:

```
<NOUNS><thing 1>hammer</thing 1><person>The Stig</person></NOUNS>
```

Comment: Nooooooo!   You just need to use some scripting that includes XML parsing.  No need to worry about return characters.  I'd strongly suggest using [tag:powershell].

Comment: Unfortunately, powershell is not an option.  If given the option, I would gladly use pretty much any other scripting language to do this.

Comment: Ok - take a look at the [second solution here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724021/parse-xml-file-with-windows-batch).  It refers to calling `xml.exe` from the batch file.  In any case, avoid DIY XML parsing :)

Comment: The xml.exe is good tool to know.  However, do to restrictions that got me into this mess, I can't use third party applications.  Initially I thought this would not be that difficult to parse with a simple batch function.  Thank you for the advise.

Comment: Why do you need to insert return characters? XML parsers don't care.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below eliminate fields that include wild card characters `*` or `?`. It may also fail if quotes are included in a field.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "part="
call :ProcessFile < file.xml > fileWithNL.xml
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   set "line=!part!!line!"
   if not defined line exit /B

   for %%a in ("!line:><=>" "<!") do (
      set "part=%%~a"
      if "!part:~-1!" equ ">" (
         echo !part!
         set "part="
      )
   )
goto ProcessFile
```

**EDIT**: *New hybrid method added*

The new solution below is a Batch-JScript hybrid script that is more efficient than the former pure Batch solution and have not its limitations. Copy the code in a file with .bat extension.

```
@set @a=0  /*
@cscript //nologo //E:Jscript "%~F0" < file.xml > fileWithNL.xml
@goto :EOF */

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/></g,">\r\n<"));
```

Answer (score 0):

save this with `.bat` extension.It accepts one argument - the xml file:

```
0</* :
@cscript /nologo /E:jscript "%~f0" %*
@goto :EOF
*/0;

var FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
if (ARGS.Length < 1 ) {
 WScript.Echo("No file passed");
 WScript.Quit(1);
}
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);

var readStream=FSOObj.OpenTextFile(filename, 1);

var content=readStream.ReadAll();
readStream.Close();

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

var newConten=replaceAll("><",">\r\n<",content);

var writeStream=FSOObj.OpenTextFile(filename, 2);
writeStream.WriteLine(newConten);
writeStream.Close();
```

Comment: The `hello` label is not needed; the first line can be just `0</* :`. It looks more cryptic this way! **`;)`** You should enclose the file name between quotes: `"%~f0"`

Comment: @Aacini  - aah yes.I was focused on the jscript part and the pattern was just copy/pasted.