# How to print a XML element value in Batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am trying to print a value from XMl file through batch script. for example, my xml file look like follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">0</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults"><str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">status</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
    <str name="Total Rows Fetched">19</str><str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
</response>
```

how to read this xml file and print "Total Rows Fetched = 19" through batch script. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that will be *incredibly* painful to do properly within just a batch file. Is there anything stopping you from using Python, Ruby, C#, ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML file with windows batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724021/parse-xml-file-with-windows-batch)

Comment: I am trying to write a batch file to automate SOLR indexing job in a window server. I have done everything except this requirement. It would be better if I get solution in batch script itself :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34925347.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-4delims=<=>" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%~b"=="str name" IF "%%~c"=="Total Rows Fetched" ECHO %%~c=%%d
 IF "%%~a"=="str name" IF "%%~b"=="Total Rows Fetched" ECHO %%~b=%%c
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34925347.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Simply partition the line using the "tokens" feature, delimiting on `<`,`=` and `>`.

If the tokens match, reconstruct the line.

Note that as posted, the leading spaces will be assigned to `%%a` so the first `if` line is invoked.

If the file is produced without the leading spaces, the assignment will be shifted by 1 place since the spaces no longer exist and hence are not interpreted as a token. The second `if` line then becomes active.

Having both `if` lines will not affect operation, unless you have a really screwy sourcefile.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :) @Magoo