# Copy from one XML to another by Windows batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a simple Windows batch (`.cmd`) script that copies some XML element from one XML file and insert it in the right place in another file.

The first XML file has a structure like this:

```
<config>
 <jx></jx>
     <roul>
         <rect>
         </rect>
         <background>
         </background>
         <text>R</text>
         <color>123</color>
         <vcenter>true</vcenter>
         <textformat>center</textformat>
         <rl>
           <r1>
             <egmid>G</egmid>
             <number>1</number>
           </r1>
           <r2>
             <egmid>C</egmid>
             <number>2</number>
           </r2>
         </rl>
 </roul>
 <a></a>
 <b><b>
</config>
```

the second (destination) xml file before the merge:

```
<config>
 <jx></jx>
     <roul>
         <rect>
         </rect>
         <background>
         </background>
         <text>R</text>
         <color>123</color>
         <vcenter>true</vcenter>
         <textformat>center</textformat>
         <rl> </rl>
 </roul>
 <a></a>
 <b><b>
</config>
```

An after the merge it should look similar to the source xml file:

```
<config>
 <jx></jx>
     <roul>
         <rect>
         </rect>
         <background>
         </background>
         <text>R</text>
         <color>123</color>
         <vcenter>true</vcenter>
         <textformat>center</textformat>
         <rl>
           <r1>
             <egmid>G</egmid>
             <number>1</number>
           </r1>
           <r2>
             <egmid>C</egmid>
             <number>2</number>
           </r2>
         </rl>
 </roul>
 <a></a>
 <b><b>
</config>
```

I need to copy all the tags that are between the `<rl>`/`</rl>` tags 
and copy them in the second XML file that looks almost the same but has no children elements between `<rl>`/`<rl>`.

The two files are in separate locations like:

- `c:/andrej/tmp1/file1.xml`
- `c:/andrej/tmp2/file2.xml`

What I learned from other posts is how to loop trough XML lines, but not how to copy and then somehow echo it or paste it to another XML file...

The code I have for now is:

```cmd
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ("c:\andrej\tmp1\file1.xml") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "newLine=!line:roulettes>=!"
    if "!newLine!" eq "!line!" (
        rem ...
    )
))
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I encourage you to attempt to solve this problem in a language that has a readily available XML parsing library (e.g., C, C++, Perl, Python, Java, Ruby, C#, PowerShell, Lisp, ...).

Parsing arbitrary XML with text parsing primitives is incredibly difficult. And Batch's text parsing primitives are weak to begin with.

(If you sufficiently limit the input, you can come up with a solution in Batch. It _is_ a complete programming language. You're going to have a bad time doing it, however.)

Comment: Possibly [helpful answer to another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19724985/2392683), similar question.

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell are all available on Windows and all have native capability to read, write and modify XML files.

Comment: Yeah, not enough information here to help you.  What will the destination XML look like?  What does "copy all the tags that are between the tags" mean?

Comment: Moreover, the code you have does not make much sense as it is searching for `roulettes>` but this does not occur in your XML file. In addition, the comparison operator is [`equ`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) rather than `eq`. Doe the tags `<rl>` and `</rl>` always appear in their own lines?

Comment: @rojo my destination xml file looks the same as the source one, only it does have no children elements in <rl></rl> so i must copy al the children nodes from one file to another from one element to the same element in the other file...

Comment: Don't just describe it.  Edit your question and paste the example destination xml before and after the merge.

Comment: *I have this somewhat complex task to do. I don't know how to do anything else, so let's do it with a batch file.* It's time to learn to use different tool for different tasks. Not everything should (or can) be done with a batch file. Writing complex user interfaces and parsing/merging XML files are two of the tasks least suited to doing from batch. Stop trying to use a hammer for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***note:*** Your XML snippets aren't fully valid, by the way.  The closer of your `<b>` tag at the bottom of all your XML examples is missing a slash.  This solution assumes you fixed that.

As others have pointed out, it's better to parse and objectify XML and other such structured markup than to hack and scrape it as flat text.  The batch language unfortunately doesn't offer much for parsing XML, but it's easy enough to borrow from other languages.

PowerShell is particularly well-suited to handle XML.  You can read an XML file as text, then cast that data as an XML object simply by prefacing it with `[XML]`.  Handy, right?  From there, select the source node from XML1 and the destination node from XML2 using XPath expressions, then import from 1 into 2.

Here's a hybrid Batch + PowerShell script demonstrating this.  Save this with a .bat extension and salt to taste.

```js
<# : batch portion (begin multiline PowerShell comment)
@echo off & setlocal

set "xml1=c:\andrej\tmp1\file1.xml"
set "xml2=c:\andrej\tmp2\file2.xml"

if not exist "%xml1%" (
    echo XML1: %xml1% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

if not exist "%xml2%" (
    echo XML2: %xml2% not found.
    exit /b 1
)

rem // relaunch self with PowerShell
powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"

rem // end of script
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

$src = [xml](gc $env:xml1)
$dest = [xml](gc $env:xml2)

$src.SelectNodes("//roul/rl/*") | %{
    "copying {0} and its descendents" -f $_.Name
    [void]$dest.SelectSingleNode("//roul/rl").AppendChild($dest.ImportNode($_, $true))
}

$dest.Save($env:xml2)
write-host "Saved changes to ${env:xml2}" -f green
# // return execution back to Batch
```

Comment: Thanks man! It is working perfectly as it is supposed to! Very much thanks for the time spent helping me! I upvoted id, but because of reputation lower than 15 it is only saved but not displayed! However thanks and thanks again, u helped me alot!