# Read Email address from xml using blat

Tags: batch-file, blat

is it possible to read xml file that contents email id separated by group ID (eg, IT, ADMIN, OTHER.....).All I want is to read the xml using **blat** with filter group id and send email to all the email ids listed in that group. Is it possible ? can anyone help me. Thanks

using batch script and blat to send email.

Comment: This is not a script writing service. Show us what you have tried so far and tell us what exactly your problem is. And read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @FatalBulletHit: I am new to batch scripting and blat, so my question was, is it possible to do that, didnt ask for the script!!!

Comment: You are welcome to ask questions, but show us what you have done to get an answer already. It's as simple as that. :)

Comment: @FatalBulletHit:  set email=p@123.com,a@i345.com,g@253.com, ...instead of this i want the email addresses  to be read from xml file, my question again is that possible using blat ??

Comment: (don't tell me in the comment, add it to your question)

Comment: XML files are text files but batch files do not have a native method to read XML files, so it would have to brute force reading the XML file.  Without knowing the format of the XML file nobody would even be able to point you in the right direction.  Use a scripting language the supports reading XML files.  VBscript, JScript or Powershell.

Comment: you haven't gave the xml file so I can't guess how it sould be parsed , but you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19725050/388389) how [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `XML` is in a similar format.

```
... beginning of xml
<ADDRESSES>
  <ADMIN>
     admin@server.com
  </ADMIN>
  <IT>
     it@server.com
  </IT>
  <OTHER>
     other@server.com
  </OTHER>
</ADDRESSES>
... rest of xml
```

You can run this:

```
@echo off
    set /p "tag=Enter Email tag: "
    set "file=xmlfile.xml"
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /i /c:"<%tag%>" "%file%"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| more +%%a') do set "email=%%i" & goto complete
)
:complete
endlocal
echo %email%
```

**NOTE!!** If your xml format is NOT in a nextline format as above, it will not work and adjustment of script is needed.