# Parse \ edit XML value using CMD batch

Tags: xml, parsing, batch-file

I need to read and potentially edit a value between tags in an XML file. I am currently limited to using a CMD batch file as the only way to process (may be able to move to power-shell in the future). "The Sample File.xml" is always in the same layout and a complete file is shown below.

The tag of interest is `<MountPoint>\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE6</MountPoint>`. I need to read the physical drive number (in this example it is 6) and edit it depending on its value. For this reason I would like to keep the read and edit components of the batch separate. Any help appreciated as my batch skills are not up to it and I haven't come close.

```
Mounting in progress, wait...
<MIPResponse Command="VIEW" Version="1.0">
<Drive>
  <IsActive>F</IsActive>
  <DeviceType>PhysicalDrive</DeviceType>
  <PartitionType>Physical</PartitionType>
  <MountPoint>\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE6</MountPoint>
  <Capacity>80026361344</Capacity>
  <CapacityString>74.53 GB</CapacityString>
<Partition>
  <IsActive>T</IsActive>
  <PartitionType>NTFS/OS2 HPFS/exFAT</PartitionType>
  <MountPoint></MountPoint>
  <Location>1048576</Location>
  <Capacity>104857600</Capacity>
  <CapacityString>100.0 MB</CapacityString>
</Partition>
<Partition>
  <IsActive>F</IsActive>
  <PartitionType>NTFS/OS2 HPFS/exFAT</PartitionType>
  <MountPoint></MountPoint>
  <Location>105906176</Location>
  <Capacity>79919316992</Capacity>
  <CapacityString>74.43 GB</CapacityString>
</Partition>
</Drive>
</MIPResponse>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A batch file to extract the value of a specific XML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217765/a-batch-file-to-extract-the-value-of-a-specific-xml-tag)

Comment: CloseVote: Questions must demonstrate a minimal attempt to solve the problem. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. At least you should be able to google before you ask a question

Comment: Do *not* treat XML files as normal plain text files! Use a language that is capable of parsing and manipulating XML data natively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ECHO Matching in file...
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "Result="
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in (
    'find /i "<MountPoint>\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE" ^< "The Sample File.xml"'
) do set "Result=%%a"
set Result=%Result:~-1%
ECHO Found Value:  PHYSICALDRIVE%Result%

ECHO Updating the other file...
powershell -Command "(gc 'The Other File.xml') -replace '"PHYSICALDRIVE[0-9]{1,2}"', '"PHYSICALDRIVE%Result%"' | Out-File -Encoding "ASCII"  'The Other File.xml'"
```